# alt attribute missing in slider revolution's transparent image

Tags: html, wordpress, revolution-slider

```
<div class="tp-bgimg defaultimg " data-bgcolor="undefined" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-image: url(&quot;https://ifycc.org/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/assets/images/transparent.png&quot;); 
background-size: cover; background-position: center center; width: 100%; height: 100%;
opacity: 1; visibility: inherit; z-index: 20;" src="https://ifycc.org/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/assets/images/transparent.png">
</div>
```

I have this code added by the slider revolution. I know they used `transparent.png` as a background image but still, SEO analyzers are giving me the warning to add alt attributes to these images. I think it's because they've also added an `src` attribute. Can anyone please guide me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the slide and under main background source settings there is a `Textbox` to enter `Alt` texts.

[image]

Comment: But this option only appears when the background is an image. How can I do this when the background is transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Was facing the same problem. However, when I downloaded Rev Slider PNG image and uploaded it as normal bg (with repeat) it has solved the problem as I have given ALT in Media Library itself.

Answer (score 1):

For those who still have this error in 2024. This appeared to me because within the sliders I had images that did not exist.

Therefore, you have to enter the slider editor where you find the empty image and delete the elements where an image icon appears with a blue background, this means that it is broken, the image does not exist.

A simple solution, but difficult to detect, hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Only good solution I found to solve the 'missing alt text' issue on the plugin's usage of `transparent.png` and `dummy.png` is to avoid them all together.

Instead of setting the background to transparent, set it to coloured and make the colour 0% opacity.

When lazy loading images, to avoid `dummy.png` being used is to set lazy loading in modules to 'no change'. Either by having that as the default and each module set to default or to have each one set to 'no change'. Default can be changed in the 'Globals' tab, and individual modules can be changed via 'Advanced' tab.

Answer (score 0):

No problem i solved inside plugin, in "alt attribute" of image background  select custom and add your text
[image]